# HTACCESS redirection — old domain to new domain, *except* home page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using the following to redirect traffic from an old domain to a new one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works great, but I need to actually redirect traffic going directly to the old site's home page to a different location. How do I add this exception?

Comment: So you want to send general 'olddomain' requests to one location and specific 'olddomain/page' requests to a different location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
## Redirect for home page requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oldhomepage.html [R=301,L]

## Redirect for all other requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oldhomepage.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Depending on where you are sending the requests for the homepage, this may need to change some, but essentially, you need to check the content of `%{REQUEST_URI}` for each `RewriteRule`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Many thanks — one question though: How do I change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/something-different` so that it catches all conditions, except requests for the home page of the old domain?

Comment: Can you provide an example URL that your old domain home page will be redirecting to?

Comment: [olddomain.com -> newdomain.com/oldhomepage.html]

[olddomain.com/anyotherpath -> newdomain.com/anyotherpath]

Comment: I updated my answer to include your example URLs/domains.  But, to answer your question, the first `RewriteRule` will handle the requests to the olddomain homepage, so the 2nd doesn't account for it.  If you would like to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$` to the second rule-set, you can to be safe.